# How to split values inside python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have values of dict stored in the form of list.
Here it is what it looks like:

```
d = [
{'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=prince,initial=p'},
{'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=steven,initial=s'}
]
```

In here, in the key `Length`, i have two values. `first=steven,initial=s`
I want to split those values and create two new fields and store it in the dictionary in the updated form.

Required Output:

```
d = [
{'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=prince,initial=p','first':'prince','initial':'p'},
{'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=steven,initial=s','first':'steven','initial':'s'}
]
```

Here's the program i tried:

```
d = [
{'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=prince,initial=p'},
{'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=steven,initial=s'}
]
field_to_split = "Length"
split_using1 = ','
split_using2 = '='
b =[]
for i in d:
    s = i[field_to_split].split(split_using1)
    print(s)
    b.append(s)
    #print(s)
print(b)
```

How can i make this possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
d = [
    {'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=prince,initial=p'},
    {'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive', 'Hybrid': 'False', 'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission', 'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6, 'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline', 'Length': 'first=steven,initial=s'}
    ]

for i in d:
    for j in i['Length'].split(","):    #Split string by comma
        i.update(dict([j.split("=")]))  #Split string by eq sign and use dict() method to create a dictionary
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission',
  'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive',
  'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline',
  'Hybrid': 'False',
  'Length': 'first=prince,initial=p',
  'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6,
  'first': 'prince',
  'initial': 'p'},
 {'Classification': 'Automatic,Transmission',
  'Driveline': 'Rear-wheel drive',
  'Fuel_Type': 'Gasoline',
  'Hybrid': 'False',
  'Length': 'first=steven,initial=s',
  'Number_of_Forward_Gears': 6,
  'first': 'steven',
  'initial': 's'}]
```